# FsCheck DataGen is null

Tags: f#, fscheck

I'm trying to work through an example of FsCheck right now for a type with discriminated unions in order to establish best practices for our larger project. Right now I am getting null from my generator and I am not sure why. In the following code, DataGen.containerGenerator is null.

```
namespace Container
open System
open Xunit
open FsCheck

module ContainerLibrary = 
    type [<Measure>] oz

    type Container = 
        | Cup of Common
        | Bowl of Common
    and Common = 
        { Volume    :decimal<oz>
          Weight    :decimal}

module DataGen = 
    type Generators = 
        static member arbVolume = 
            FsCheck.Gen.choose (1, 16)
            |> FsCheck.Gen.map(fun x -> (decimal x / 8.0M) * 1.0M<ContainerLibrary.oz>)
            |> FsCheck.Arb.fromGen

    FsCheck.Arb.register<Generators>() |> ignore

    let bowlGenerator = 
        FsCheck.Gen.map2 (fun a b -> ContainerLibrary.Bowl( { Volume = a 
                                                              Weight = b})) 
                         (Generators.arbVolume.Generator) 
                         (FsCheck.Arb.generate<decimal>)
    let cupGenerator =
        FsCheck.Gen.map2 (fun a b -> ContainerLibrary.Cup( { Volume = a 
                                                             Weight = b})) 
                         (Generators.arbVolume.Generator) 
                         (FsCheck.Arb.generate<decimal>)

    let containerGenerator =
        Gen.oneof [bowlGenerator; cupGenerator]

module Tests =
    [<Fact;>]
    let ``01 : Containers must be no more than 20 oz`` () =
        //Is this the best way to get one of something?
        let c = FsCheck.Gen.sample 0 1 DataGen.containerGenerator |> Seq.head
        Assert.NotNull (c)
```

Comment: Map your gen to `NonNull<T>` to avoid null instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be null when I run it, even when I get more values. Which version of FsCheck are you using?

```
[<Fact;>]
let ``01 : Containers must be no more than 20 oz`` () =
    //Is this the best way to get one of something?
    Gen.sample 0 100 DataGen.containerGenerator |> Seq.iter(fun c -> printf "%A" c; Assert.NotNull (c))
```

In any case, there are several things to note about what you're doing.

- FsCheck uses reflection to register generators; and type of measure type parameters cannot be seen by reflection. So the Arb.register would actually override the decimal generator, for all decimals.
- Somehow the FsCheck. qualifications you used confused intellisense no end.
- Gen.sample is a reasonable way to test generators but I mostly use it in interactive settings; if you've gone through the trouble of setting up a test I tend to use FsCheck's built in test-case observation capabilities. See "Observing test case distribution" here: https://fsharp.github.io/FsCheck/Properties.html
- Using Arb.register in the module init like you're doing is a bit brittle, depending on module initialization rules in F# to register generators. If you're using Xunit, it's much better to use the built-in integration to reduce inevitable frustration in this area.

I've rewritten your example a bit taking some of these things into account:

```
module DataGen = 

open ContainerLibrary

//can't really register this one because of the measure, would override all decimal generatos
let volumeGenerator = 
        Gen.choose (1, 16)
        |> Gen.map(fun x -> (decimal x / 8.0M) * 1.0M<ContainerLibrary.oz>)

let commonGenerator =
    Gen.map2 (fun a b -> { Volume = a 
                           Weight = b})
                     (volumeGenerator) 
                     (Arb.generate<decimal>)

//in case you like applicative style, otherwise completely equivalent
let commonGeneratorAlternative =
    (fun a b -> { Volume = a; Weight = b}) <!> volumeGenerator <*> Arb.generate<decimal>

let bowlGenerator = Gen.map Bowl commonGenerator
let cupGenerator = Gen.map Cup commonGenerator

let containerGenerator =
    Gen.oneof [bowlGenerator; cupGenerator]

type Generators =
    static member Container() = containerGenerator |> Arb.fromGen

module Tests =
open FsCheck.Xunit
open ContainerLibrary

//use PropertyAttribute from FsCheck.Xunit
//use the defined container generator - can also move this to module level
//other ways to parametrize
[<Property(Arbitrary=[|typeof<DataGen.Generators>|])>]
//thanks to PropertyAttribute can now just take container as argument
let ``01 : Containers must be no more than 20 oz`` (container:Container) =
    match container with
    | Cup common
    | Bowl common -> common.Volume <= 20.0M<oz>
    |> Prop.collect container //see the generated values in the output
```

This outputs something like:

Ok, passed 100 tests.

1% Cup {Volume = 2.0M;
     Weight = -0.0000221360928858744815609M;}.
1% Cup {Volume = 1.8750M;
     Weight = 922337.20325598085121M;}.
etc